# On the performance of DCT-based OFDM

Tags: fft, digital-communications, ofdm, dct

I am trying to understand the OFDM based on DCT instead of DFT in order to compare between their performance. In case of AWGN, the performance is logic, but when I perform channel equalization in DCT-domain, I don't get the performance back ! I think the equalization in DCT domain should be performed in different way. Is that right to perform that process as:

- Data sequence -->
- S/P -->
- IDCT -->
- CP insertion -->
- P/S -->
- Channel + noise -->
- S/P -->
- CP removal -->
- DCT -->
- DCT for channel -->
- channel equalization -->
- received data sequence

That process was performed in Matlab as below :

```
clear all; clc; clear; 

N = 1024;     %number of symbol 
M = 2;       %Modulation order 
CP = N/4;     %The CP length 
Num_sym = 1; %Number of symbols 


SNR = 1 : 5 : 35; 
BER_OFDM = zeros(1,length(SNR)); 

for t = 1:length(SNR)
    t
    for t2 = 1:10^1 

    L = 32; 
    h = randn(L,1) + 1j*randn(L,1);   %Generate the channel 


    X = randi([0 1] ,N*Num_sym, 1);        %% Generate data 
    X_mod = qammod(X,M);                   %%Data modulation 

    X_tr = idct(X_mod);                     %%% IDCT operation
    %%%%  
    X_cp = [X_tr(end-CP+1:end); X_tr];       %%Adding CP 
    X_chanel = conv(h,X_cp);                 %%Convolution with channel 
    X_chanel = awgn(X_chanel,SNR(t),'measured');  %%Add the noise
    Y = X_chanel(CP+1:end-L+1);               %%Remove CP and delay 

    H = dct(h,N);                           %Channel in DCT frequency-domain

    EbNo_lin = 10^(SNR(t)/10);                 %linear scale 
    Gz = conj(H) ./ (H.*conj(H) + 1./EbNo_lin);   %%Equalizer coefficients

    Y_rec = dct(Y);                            %%DCT operation

    Y_r = Y_rec.*Gz;                          %%Equalization

    sym_r = qamdemod(Y_r,M);                      %Demodularing received signal 
    sym_t = qamdemod(X_mod,M);                    %Demodularing transmitting signal

    errors_OFDM = sum(xor(sym_r,sym_t));
    BER_OFDM(t) = errors_OFDM + BER_OFDM(t); 


    end 

end 

err_ber_OFDM = BER_OFDM/(N*log2(M))./10;

semilogy(SNR, err_ber_OFDM, 'k-','LineWidth',1)
hold on
xlabel('SNR (dB)');
ylabel('BER');
grid on
```

I get such performance as below figure, but I don't think that the performance of OFDM-based DCT is too bad like. I think the channel equalization should be done in different way, but I don't know how

[image]

Comment: do you have any source describing this DCT-OFDM? That can only work on real-valued channels (being inherently symmetrical), but yours seems to be a complex channel – i.e. your channel has twice as many degrees of freedom than every DCT coefficient, and hence, you can't compensate it?

Comment: I am following these two articles  https://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/813429/   and this one https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4012512    ... I tried to make the channel as only real values, but I still can't get the performance.

Comment: perspectively, how do you plan to employ this? If you're using QAM, you say "this channel is complex", but then you can't restrict yourself to using a real channel model like you're doing now... unless your complex channel is really just two separate real baseband channels, but that sounds unrealistic

Comment: You are definitely right. So, I'm using BPSK modulation since the signal in DCT is real. but they channel is not always real at least according to the two papers in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm reading the [original DCT-OFDM paper](https://wwwpub.utdallas.edu/~nxa028000/DCT.pdf) right now – this is kind of a um, how do I put this? A system ignoring its purpose? They show that DCT-OFDM works just as well as DFT-OFDM (at making a channel equalizer unnecessary to use a wideband channel), by requiring a prefilter, which is an MSE-equalizer that makes the channel symmetric, thereby completely forgetting that the whole point of OFDM was to not require that kind of equalizer.

Comment: ah, the point is that they assume a channel-shortening filter is used, anyways, and needs to be designed, anyways (that's not a very common thing for most OFDM systems as far as I'm aware – but I can't look into industry-secret OFDM implementations), and say that their design method needs less computation; OK, then. So, you're missing that prefilter; even if your channel doesn't need to be symmetricized (after which you can use QAM again), the prefilter still is a channel-shortening equalizer, and should already drastically improve any system's performance.

Comment: But in most systems, they don't use channel-shortening filters with DCT-based OFDM  including the two papers I have included in my comment. Is it important to use prefilter with DCT-based OFDM in all cases? Could you please write that reply as a reply including more details ?

Comment: As we've estaiblished, you can't correct a complex channel with a DCT, right? so, you need a system that makes your channel symmetric, first. don't see how it would work without.

Comment: You can do that by converting the received signal $Y$ into frequency domain using fft, then equalize with frequency-domain channel $fft(h,N)$, after that, use ifft and finally dct, That work well when assuming perfect knowledge of channel,  but I don't know how can we estimate the channel in that case.

Comment: Yes. that worked, but I need to estimate the channel too.

Comment: You can study the channel estimation in that case since pilot are known at receiver side and using real or complex pilot symbols gives almost the same performance of channel estimation. I think you can do it.

Comment: Unless you can use the method provided by Marcus as in this link https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8291595